# Program outputting values without initial referencing of Variables(BULLS AND COWS)

Tags: c, initialization

So here is the deal , I was writing a Bulls and Cows Game in `C` and had an interesting observation..It was that my program was outputting values without initial referencing....First look at the whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int i,j,bulls,cows;
    //int bulls = 0;
    //int cows = 0;
    char guess[4];
    char chosenword[4] = "onea";
    puts("Enter Your best guess <4 letter word>");
    gets(guess);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(guess[i] == chosenword[i]){
            bulls++;
        }
        else {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                if(chosenword[i]==guess[j]){
                    cows++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Bulls: %d And Cows: %d",bulls,cows);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I have not initialized the variables bulls and cows to 0 but still my program outputs 
some value or the other eg :
[image]

Here as you can see there are three trials..while the value of bulls changes the value of cows remains constant. Can anyone please explain the logic?

Answer (score 2):

Because, other than the initialization, your variable contains some garbage value. You cannot predict what is that value.

In your code, `bulls` and `cows` are local variable in [`auto`]. So, compiler won't be initializing them, unless you do so explicitly in your code.

<sup>In contrast to using `static` or making them global.</sup>

Without initialization, using `bulls++;` or `cows++` is creating a scenario `read-before-write` which may very well lead to undefined behavior. Always initialize your variables.

To avoid the issue: Please uncomment the initialization part in your code. :-)

A word of advice : Please don't use `gets()`. Use `fgets()`. Its lot safer.

Next,

```
char guess[4];
char chosenword[4] = "onea";
```

change to

```
char guess[5];                //to hold the terminating null character also
char chosenword[ ] = "onea";   //while initializing, you don't need to specify size explicitly.
```

---

EDIT:

In your case, cow is producing *constant* output because for *your* inputs, `if` condition never fails.

Comment: Initializing is correct. Using statics, or making them global is a bad practice here.  Just setting them equal to zero is the correct approach

Comment: Thank you for that but then why is the value of cows constant?

Comment: @AhmedMasud and why's that?

Comment: dear @downvoter, care to state the reason too, please?

Comment: Since the variables are not initialized, it does not really matter why the value of `cows` is always the same. It may change on the next run or tomorrow or when compiled on a different machine a.s.o. It is just undefined behavior and any other value it will output (even `0`) it is wrong.

Comment: Using globals in general is a bad programming practice, unless you are doing something that applies globally.  Getting into the habit of using local variables, especially as a new programmer is a much better practice. Globals/statics should be used very sparingly. Also, global variables and static variables behave differently, telling a new programmer to use one of them without explaining the impact is also confusing in the long run. I downvoted you for it.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I got your point. maybe i have chosen wrong words. Hope now it's fine.

Comment: `gets()` or `fgets()`, it still has a buffer overflow. `guess` should accommodate at least 4 characters plus the terminating null character (i.e. at least 5).

Comment: @axiac agree, but it is not _fatal_ unless you're using `guess` as a string.

Comment: Great +1 to your answer now... Can you also show an example of how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid using `gets()` instead use `fgets()`.

Using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior.
The value of uninitialized variables is undeterminate. The values you are seeing are some garbage values. So once we say UB anything might happen and explanation for it doesn't make sense.
Please initialize your local variables in order to get right outputs.